# How to parse month-year string using Presto

Tags: type-conversion, presto, trino

I have a column that contains a Month-Year string that I would like to convert to an actual date representing the first day of the Month and Year combination. For example

```
+----------+------------+
| Original | Desired    |
+----------+------------+
| Aug-19   | 08/01/2019 |
+----------+------------+
| Sep-20   | 09/01/2020 |
+----------+------------+
| May-22   | 05/01/2022 |
+----------+------------+
```

I have tried breaking apart the *Month-Year* string using `split_part` but when I try and pass *Month* as a parameter into `date_parse` it throws an error with the input (`INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT`). I could break apart the *Month-Year* into strings and then recombine, hard-coding the `01` however the problem seems that three letter month cannot be parsed into an actual month by Presto. I also want to avoid a 12 line CASE WHEN statement to parse the month if possible.

Comment: data_parse function's `%b` expects 3 char, but your data contains 4 char (Sept). You will need to shorten the data.

Comment: That extra `t` was actually my error. I have since corrected it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where the year comes from, but the query will be like this:

```sql
select date_format(date_parse('May-22', '%b-%d'), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?mysql-date-functions